# How to color a Qt QComboBox on MacOSX?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, user-interface

This seems a common problem but I still haven't found a solution that works. I know QComboBox is a complex control, but there must be a way to smoothly change the palette(background color, text color, etc) while keeping the OS style and not having to re-invent the wheel? I am also having the same issues with QPushButton it seems...

I am using Qt 5.15.3 on MacOSX 12.4 - Monterey.

I have tried the palette approach, which doesn't seem to update the colors except for the non-selected items.
I have tried to update the styleSheet properties but this gets rid of the OS styling and goes back to an old style looking widget.

My code sample looks like this:

```
QPalette pal = qApp->palette();
pal.setColor(QPalette::Window, Qt::black);
pal.setColor(QPalette::WindowText, Qt::white);
pal.setColor(QPalette::Text, Qt::white);
pal.setColor(QPalette::ButtonText, Qt::white);
pal.setColor(QPalette::Button, Qt::darkGray);
pal.setColor(QPalette::Base, Qt::darkGray);
pal.setColor(QPalette::AlternateBase, Qt::gray);
pal.setColor(QPalette::Light, Qt::white);
pal.setColor(QPalette::Midlight,Qt::gray);
pal.setColor(QPalette::Dark, Qt::darkGray);
qApp->setPalette(pal);

// qApp->setStyleSheet("QComboBox { background-color: gray}"); // Works, but removes the OS styling
// ui->comboBox->setStyleSheet("border:none"); // Same
// ui->comboBox->setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Macintosh")); // No change, it sill keeps the "Windows" styling
// ui->comboBox->setAutoFillBackground(true); // Paints behind the combo box only

// ui->comboBox->setPalette(pal); // Doesn't change anything
// ui->comboBox->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Base); // Doesn't change anything`
```

This is the result:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBJ1V.png)

What is left to try?

Comment: Some of the methods you already tried might work better if you use the "Fusion" style.  Add this code near the beginning of main:  `QApplication::setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("fusion"));`

Comment: @DavidGrayson Thank you, I would prefer to keep the same style as the other controls, which I get "Macintosh". I have to try to set it back after updating the stylesheet with setStyle(), but it somehow sticks to "Window" style anyway.

Comment: I was suggesting you use "Fusion" for your entire app, not just for one control.